# Regex: select only a part of the expression

Tags: sql, regex, teradata

I am new to regular expressions, so it might be an easy solution or perhaps it is better to use something else for this. Note that I am using `teradata SQL assistant`.

The kind of patterns I have in my data:

- `99 A`
- `99 Box 1`
- `99 Box 1B`
- `999 B`
- `999 Bx 1`

These are house numbers with sometimes a box number attached to them. I want to pick only the house number, that is sometimes e.g. in the format of `99 A` in which case `A` should be picked also.

So the result of my regular expression (or if you have a better alternative, feel free) for the above four cases should be:

- `99 A`
- `99`
- `99`
- `99 B`
- `999`
- `999`

Comment: What dbms are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Teradata has also the [REGEXP_SUBSTR](http://www.teradatawiki.net/2014/05/regular-expression-functions.html) function

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(house_number,'^\d+(\s+\w$)?') as house_number_without_box
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: @RhythemAggarwal It's a pretty basic regex actually.  `^` : start of the line, `\d+` : one or more digits `(\s+\w$)?` : optional capture group `()?` of one or more whitespaces `\s+` & one word character `\w` followed by the end of the line `$`.

Comment: Side note: If there are house numbers like "12A" without a space. Then just change the `\s+` to `\s*`. `\s*`: 0 or more whitespaces.

Comment: This is indeed what I was after, thanks a lot for the extra explanation too.

Comment: @LukStorms It works perfect, but what part exactly ensures that it takes `99` instead of `99 Box` (don't get me wrong: I want it to perform like this, I am just trying to understand how the regex only picks the words with 1 character).

Comment: @Anonymous  Because of the `$` in the optional capture group.  `\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.  So `\w$` is a word-character at the end of a line.

Answer (score 1):

Simple enough solution if your sample data is concise to your whole data set.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEN(field) = 4 THEN field ELSE LEFT(field, 2)
FROM yourtable
```

Comment: Do you actually think there are always two-digit house number?

Comment: @dnoeth Do you have any evidence from the OP's sample data that would say otherwise? Hence why I stated `if your sample data is concise to your whole data set.`

Comment: As @dnoeth notes, there can be 3 digits as well. I'd like to have it as flexible as possible. I was probably unclear. Otherwise, this would work when I use `LENGTH`, instead of `LEN`

Comment: @Anonymous Yup, sample data should include  at least 1 of each possible length/type/format of data. OR give the range of possibilities in an explanation.

Comment: My bad, thank you for providing this answer though. It is useful to keep in mind these functions in the future.

Answer (score 0):

this will solve your question

```
SELECT case when position('box' IN field)= 0 then field else 
                    substr(field, 1, length(field) - position('box' IN field) )  end
FROM yourtable
```

Comment: This throws a syntax error 3707: expected something like an 'END' keyword between ')' and the 'SUBSTR' keyword.

Comment: `position('box' IN field)` after `else` must be removed

Comment: That works indeed. It is however specific to only being able to detect 'box', as soon as it is something else it won't work. But that's my bad for not formulating the question and possibilities broader

Comment: @Anonymous: So what *are* those possibilities?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider this solution with regular expression:

```
select * from table where (reason regexp '(^[0-9][0-9]+$)|(^[0-9][0-9]+ [A-Z]?$)')
```

Comment: This is a WHERE-condition, but doesn't extract the number

Comment: Got it, My bad. i did not see the edit on the question!! Thanks for pointing it out!